# How to pass custom props to component in Vue from function?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I want to pass `isReadonly` boolean value from first component to second.
And it does not work.

Edited after cafertayyar answer.
Method `isReadonly` moved from `methods` to `computed`.

First component:

```
<template>
    <PreliminaryInformationUsageCode :is-readonly="isReadonly" />
</template>

<script>
    import PreliminaryInformationUsageCode from './form/PreliminaryInformationUsageCode.vue'
    export default {
        name: 'FormPage',
        computed: {
            form() {
                return this.$store.getters['form/form']
            },
            isReadonly: function() {
                //return true
                return false
            }
        },
        components: {
            PreliminaryInformationUsageCode,
        },
    }
</script>
```

Second component:

```
<template>
    <v-select
      v-model="usageCodesSelected"
      :items="usageCodes"
      item-text="name"
      item-value="code"
      label="Label"
      multiple
      hint="Hint"
      persistent-hint
      v-bind:readonly="isReadonly"
    >
        <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
            <v-chip v-if="index === 0">
                <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
            </v-chip>
            <span
              v-if="index === 1"
              class="grey--text text-caption"
            >
                (+{{ usageCodesSelected.length - 1 }} дополнительно)
            </span>
        </template>
    </v-select>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'PreliminaryInformationUsageCode',
        props: {
            isReadonly: {
                Boolean
            },
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                usageCodesSelected: [
                ],
                usageCodes: [
                ],
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<PreliminaryInformationUsageCode :is-readonly="isReadonly"/>
```

and instead of using `isReadonly` function, define a computed like:

```
computed: {
   isReadonly() {
      return this.form.status.seq != 10;
   }
}
```

Comment: It is still does not work. Do I need to add variable in data? Or I can directly use it from props?

Comment: I dont have any error message. My select field have always readonly true.

Comment: What happens when computed is like: `computed: { isReadonly() {  return false;  } }`

Comment: It works! Is method block bad for such conditions?

Comment: Is `this.form.status.seq` always different than 10?

Comment: I getting form object from API. Status seq can be 10-70.
10 means Draft.

Comment: In PreliminaryInformationUsageCode the prop isReadonly must be Boolean like : `props: { isReadonly: { Boolean }, }`